# how to use more than one core of a cpu in an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis-7, cpu

I have a multicore processor on my windows 2012 server. I'm planning to add a background thread to my the aps.net application running on that server. Can i expect my application to use more then one core of the cpu? Meaning the page request are served with one core and the background thread get an other core of the cpu. 
If not how can i otherwise achieve this goal?
many thanks in advance

B

Comment: Hi Habib, is this comment related to my question?

Comment: No not at all, I posted the comment on the wrong question. Had multiple windows opened. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568264/asp-net-web-app-or-windows-desktop-application) was the intended question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS will spread the processing of requests across all available cores (unless configured otherwise by specifying a processor affinity). Hence ASP.NET will also makes full use of all processor cores.  If you intention is to spin up a new thread/Task during your application start in global.asax then yes, this will be scheduled to run on an available core. Keep in mind though that this background process will be killed/re-launched on application pool recycling.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for. Is it possible to verify in any way that this is in fact a the case. is there any kind of profiling tool that can reveal this information in a production environment?

Comment: Well, Task Manager can show you how many cores are being utilised and how many threads each Process is managing. You could also log the Thread ID (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) as part of your Page & BG Task processing.  If you dont have any logging yet then I suggest you add it.  Log4Net is useful in this respect.